# Receive second answer from server via Python Sockets

Tags: python, bash, sockets

**My goal** - I have the following situation. When i connect with netcat/telnet to a port the following 'conversation' happens:

Server: give me your pincode.
Client: ******
Server: Wrong (Or good)

For security test purposes i would like to script this task. I already got this succesfully done via Bash but i will also try to do it with python.

**My script**

```
import socket
for i in range(1000,9999):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(('localhost',31337))
    s.send (i)              # send pincode to server
    answerfromserver = s.recv(1024)     
    print answerfromserver
    s.close
```

**My problem & question**
I only receive the first answer ("give me your pincode") from the server, i'm not able to receive the second answer (if the pincode is correct/wrong). Who can help me to accomplish this?

Comment: Because you close the socket before you reveive it

Comment: Thanks. But how kan i fix this in combination with the for loop. How can i develop the script to receive (recv()) twice before go to the next itteration of the loop?

Comment: ok wait I am writing a complete answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this, notice that when the second answer is good I don't close the socket to let you do your stuff:

```
import socket

for i in range(1000, 9999):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(('localhost', 31337))
    answerfromserver = None
    while True:
        answerfromserver = s.recv(1024)
        if answerfromserver:
            if answerfromserver == "give me your pincode":
                print answerfromserver
                s.send(i)
            else:
                print i, answerfromserver
                break
    if answerfromserver == 'Good':
        # stuff
        break
    else:
        s.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, it hangs the second itteration of the while at "answerfromserver = s.recv(1024)", waiting for the Good/Bad pincode answer from the server.   For some reason i can't get it working in Python. It's not a server issue, because it works fine with netcat and with a bash script